# NSTableView multi-column drag reorder rows and include all columns

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

We have an app where the user can drag-reorder rows in a single column tableView OR with multi-column tableViews. It works but the drag only shows the string from the clicked on column - it essentially looks like this when dragging.

[image]

We want to enhance the UI so when the drag occurs, the rows animate (move) but also include the strings from all columns in the drag.

With our new code, the issue is when when the drag occurs, the origin.x is not correct - the image is either too far to the left or right. We were having difficuly even having the drag image appear in the list (it 'zooomed' in from outside the window in our first attempts) so by adding a temporary coordinate in for X, it worked better, but still isn't right.

Here's what it looks like when clicking and dragging in column 0, 1 and then 2

[image: Col_0_drag]

[image: Col_1_drag]

[image: Col_2_drag]

The tableView delegate code

```
//get the row index to be dragged and store it on the pasteboard as a string
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
    let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
    pasteboardItem.setString( String(row), forType: .tableViewIndex)
    return pasteboardItem
}

//handle the drag
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession, willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint, forRowIndexes rowIndexes: IndexSet) {
    let draggedRow = rowIndexes.first!
    let rowView = tableView.rowView(atRow: draggedRow, makeIfNecessary: true)! //get the view of the row
    let draggingRect = tableView.rect(ofRow: rowIndexes.first!)

    let localMouseDownPoint = self.view.window?.convertPoint(fromScreen: screenPoint) //where did we mousedown in the window

    session.enumerateDraggingItems(options: [], for: tableView, classes: [NSPasteboardItem.self], searchOptions: [:]) { dragItem, _, _ in
        print("drag origin", dragItem.draggingFrame.origin)
        let snap = rowView.snapshot()
        let size = NSSize(width: draggingRect.width, height: dragItem.draggingFrame.height)
        let p = NSPoint(x: -500.0, y: dragItem.draggingFrame.origin.y) //inserted -500 here to at least get the drag in the window
        let frame = NSRect(origin: p, size: size)
        dragItem.setDraggingFrame(frame, contents: snap)
    }
}

//allow the drop for the .move operation
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> NSDragOperation {
    guard dropOperation == .above else { return [] }
    //will add code to block drags from other sources
    tableView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = .regular

    return .move
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, row: Int, dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
    guard let pbItems = info.draggingPasteboard.pasteboardItems else { return false }

    let pbItem = pbItems.first!
    guard let oldIndexString = pbItem.string(forType: .tableViewIndex) else { return false }
    guard let oldIndex = Int(oldIndexString) else { return false }
    let oldIndexSet = IndexSet(integer: oldIndex)

    ItemManager.itemArray.move(with: oldIndexSet, to: row)

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    if oldIndex < row {
        tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndex, to: row - 1)
    } else {
        tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndex, to: row)
    }

    tableView.endUpdates()

    return true
}
```

Conceptually, instead of using the String to show as the item to be dragged, we capture an image of the entire row and use that instead - which works.

However, the placement is where the issue is - if the user clicks on the text in any column, the image should 'pick up the row' where that click is, not off to the left or right.

One thing we cannot determine how to correctly use is the

```
session.enumerateDraggingItems
```

The documentation is weak and what dragItem is actually populated with is unclear to us - it says the coordinates are in relation to the view it's contained in but this

```
print("drag origin", dragItem.draggingFrame.origin)
```

Revels an origin that's all negative numbers. Possibly flipped? And it appears the initial properties reflect the *cell view* that was clicked?

Comment: If you replace the image of the cell with the image of the row then `dragItem.draggingFrame.origin.x` should move to the left by `cellView.x - rowView.x`.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for taking a look. Can you clarify what `cellView` refers to? What views coordinate system is `rowView.x`? TableView would be 0 obviously but is it the Windows? The screen?

Comment: `cellView` is the cell view, usually a `NSTableCellView`, whose image is being replaced. Both frames must be converted to the same coordinate space. A superview of both is the table view.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you. If the tableView is used as the superView, cellView.x will be that cells origin position within the tableView, but then won't the `rowView.x` be the rowViews origin in the tableView, which will always be 0 as the rowView origin is on the bottom left corner of the rowView within the tableView?

Comment: If it's documented then yes.

Comment: @Willeke Can you provide some clarity on your comment? The suggestion is to move the dragging frame to the left by the equation stated above and you state it's in the tableView coordinate system. My question remains; if `rowView.x` is always 0 (in the tableView coordinates), then the equation you suggested `cellView.x - rowView.x` will just resolve to `cellView.x` which then doesn't position it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dragItem.draggingFrame` is the frame of the cell in a mysterious coordinate space. To calculate the frame of the row in this coordinate space, adjust `dragItem.draggingFrame` by the difference between the frames of the row view and cell view. In my test app:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession,
    willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint, forRowIndexes rowIndexes: IndexSet) {
    guard let windowPoint = tableView.window?.convertPoint(fromScreen: screenPoint) else { return }
    let tableViewPoint = tableView.convert(windowPoint, from: nil)
    let columnIndex = tableView.column(at: tableViewPoint)
    let rowIndex = tableView.row(at: tableViewPoint)
    if columnIndex >= 0,
        let cellView = tableView.view(atColumn: columnIndex, row: rowIndex, makeIfNecessary: true) {
        let xOffset = cellView.frame.origin.x
        session.enumerateDraggingItems(options: [], for: tableView, classes: [NSPasteboardItem.self], searchOptions: [:]) { dragItem, _, _ in
            if let pbItem = dragItem.item as? NSPasteboardItem,
                let row = pbItem.propertyList(forType: .tableViewIndex) as? Int,
                let rowView = tableView.rowView(atRow: row, makeIfNecessary: true),
                let image = NSImage(data: rowView.dataWithPDF(inside: rowView.bounds)) {

                // adjust draggingFrame
                var origin = dragItem.draggingFrame.origin
                origin.x -= xOffset
                let frame = NSRect(origin: origin, size: image.size)
                dragItem.setDraggingFrame(frame, contents: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the `tableView:dragging session` code in my question with your code. It uses `.propertyList` which mine didn't so I adjusted my code to match. The results are not as expected and crashes. 1) If the first row is dragged down the list, it works. However, the same operation crashes immediately when the drag starts `Row index -1 out of row range (numberOfRows: 5) for <NSTableView:`. 2) Dragging the bottom row to the top drags, but upon dropping, the first three rows disappear. If your code is commented out, the drag works, but only the clicked column text drags.

Comment: Note that if I add a breakpoint at the first line `guard let windowPoint` and run the code, drag and drop `let rowIndex = tableView.row(at: tableViewPoint)` resolves to 0 the first time. Running it again, `rowIndex` resolves to -1 the second time causing the crash. Something in `enumerateDraggingItems` is 'messing' with the index. You can see the index is incorrect by adding a `print("rowIndex", rowIndex)` right after the row it's assigned on.

Comment: `rowIndex` is always correct in my test app, so I have no idea what's wrong. What happens if you comment out `session.enumerateDraggingItems` or `dragItem.setDraggingFrame`?

Comment: hold up. I think I found the issue. I set `validateDrop` `tableView.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle` to `.gap` for the animation and forgot to set it back to `.regular.` With regular, it appears to be working. I wonder why `.gap` causes an issue.

Comment: `NSTableVIew` is a mess. `row(at:)`, `hitTest(_:)` and others don't work when the gap is inserted.